# iOS Autoshrink not working on single word in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using autolayout to have a multiline UILabel auto size the text to fit does not work for single words.

Here is how storyboard is set up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the problem.

This does not display properly:

[image]

But this does:

[image]

I have adjusted every setting in the storyboard. I have changed all of the Line Break settings (wrap, truncate, etc), I have adjusted # of lines, I have made text plain vs attributed, I've changed font sizing and scaling, everything. What am I missing? Why does "California" get cut off instead of shrinking to fit? I've seen many other posts on SO and haven't yet found a solution (which needs to be compatible back to iOS 9)

Comment: What constraints do you have on the label?

Comment: I've tried to fix the width, I have tried aspect ratio, I've tried centered to a superview...

Comment: Are you still have this issue?  If so, you could create a project with just this in it and I could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your label is being filled both horizontally and vertically until it runs out of space, then it starts shrinking the text to fit. In the one word example it breaks the word into two lines because there is vertical room.

Do you know in advance or can you calculate in the app when you have only one word in this label? If so you can change the number of lines to 1 instead of 0 so the app will keep the contents on one line and shrink this word.

Comment: I do, but the problem persists with multiple lines also. If the text is "I Like California" then  "I like" is on the first line and "California" still gets broken up into two lines. But your comment about available vertical space helps.